# Bootstrap model pop showing status -3 error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap popup model as follows :

```
<div class="modal modal-top fade assigns-modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            Content goes here....
             </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And I am calling it as

```
<a href=".assigns-modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-privileges" data-toggle="modal"> Open </a>
```

On click it is not opening a popup with specified content. But it is showing a error in json format

```
{"status":-3,"message":"Unable to reach server at this moment, please try after some time."}
```

I am not able to resolve this error. Because it is working fine as a plain HTML but once i integrate it with PHP page.

Any help is appreciable.

Thanks.

**Edit**

I can see the GET call in firbug console.

```
GET http://localhost/project/admin/.assigns-modal 200 OK 43ms
```

Comment: That's neither HTML nor JavaScript. Please add the PHP file that generates it.

Comment: PHP file just generating a multiple links which will invoke this model.

Comment: Looks like the error is generated from PHP and not the JavaScript.

Comment: Also I can see the GET call.Please check my edits

Comment: What's the output of the GET call? The response

Comment: The same {"status":-3,"message":"Unable to reach server at this moment, please try after some time."} Which getting display in popup

Comment: What the *** is inside `http://localhost/project/admin/.assigns-modal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, in your `href`, you give something with a `#hash` for two reasons:

1. `#` is used to select elements using `id`.
2. `#` doesn't navigate away from the page.

So please change your `.assigns-modal` to `#assigns-modal`.

Comment: Thanks @Praveen I have changed assigns-modal class to id and it is working fine now .....